How is Petrarch using an ... an in this passage?
In Invectiva contra quendam magni status hominem, Petrarch complains that his former friend, who used to be very complimentary of him, has recently been calling him ignorant. Petrarch asked what has changed to cause this change of opinion. Petrarch thinks it's because his friend recently became a cardinal and now looks down on people he used to look up to.
Most of the treatise is straightforward, but I am stumbling a bit over this sentence, particularly the use of an... an:

Nunc autem an quia maiusculus, ego nichil, an tuum hoc solium
vel te alium, vel me fecit?

David Marsh translates it so: "If you are now somewhat greater, and I am nothing, which one of us was changed by your throne, you or me?"
Marsh's translation treats the first an as setting up a premise, with the second an introducing a question based on that premise.
To put it differently, he seems to bracket the sentence this way:

[Nunc autem]
[an quia maiusculus, ego nichil,]
[an tuum hoc solium vel te alium, vel me fecit?]

My understanding is that the two an clauses should be parallel, sharing the predicate, like this:

[Nunc autem]
[an quia maiusculus, ego nichil,]
[an tuum hoc solium]
[vel te alium, vel me fecit?]

Roughly translated, "Now then, is it the fact that you are somewhat greater and I am nothing that has changed either you or me, or is it this throne of yours [that has done so]?"
Or perhaps the second an clause is not a true second option, but just a way of rephrasing the first one?

I don't have access to a critical edition (except Google Books snippets), but it does look like this sentence has conflicting readings. In fact, many older editions have, "Nunc autem an quia maiusculus, ego sum nichil vel totum? Hoc solium, etc." One Italian edition mentions the newer reading as coming from "M O R" (presumably three manuscripts?). In any case, I think the translator's attempt makes the most sense, assuming there isn't any corruption.
